# Change numbers to specific name in properly step in two different columns by using bash script (awk, sed, etc)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

My input (a very small part of my document and I also must use this program on 100 documents):

```
86834 SOL4504
86955 SOL5240
86963 SOL4251
SOL15 38222
SOL17 35642
SOL110 41053
```

My output:

```
MGD674 SOL4504
MGD675 SOL5240
MGD675 SOL4251
SOL15 MGD297
SOL17 MGD277
SOL110 MGD319
```

In my program, I want to change the number to a specific name. For number from 1 to 129, I change the number to name MGD1 (for example number: 1, name: MGD1; another example number: 92, name: MGD1; another example number 12905, name: MGD101, etc.). I also must do this operation in 100 files.

First of all, I think to do this in this way, but you can create **COMPLETELY DIFFERENT** code:

```
#!/bin/bash
MGD_atom_index=1
number=1
MGD_mol_index=MGD$number
for index in {1..100} // I do this script on 100 files, that's why I use for loop
do
    for MGD_index in {1..900} //I run this 900 times for each file, because for every name (for example for every MGD1 program try to find and replace number, I will have max MGD900, because the highest number is 116100, so 116100/129 = 900.
    do
            sed -i "s/$MGD_atom_index/$MGD_mol_index/g;s/$(($MGD_atom_index+1))/$MGD_mol_index/g;s/$(($MGD_atom_index+2))/$MGD_mol_index/g.(this code will be very long, because I need write " s/$(($MGD_atom_index+2))/$MGD_mol_index/g" until I have $MGD_atom_index+128.....s/$(($MGD_atom_index+128))/$MGD_mol_index/g" new2_$index.ndx
        MGD_atom_index=$(($MGD_atom_index+129)) // I change atom index so for example first I look for numbers from 1 to 129 and change it to MGD1 and now I will find numbers from 130 to 258 and looking for MGD2
        number=$(($number+1))
        MGD_mol_index=SOL$number I change  and now I try to find and replace MGD2
    done
    MGD_atom_index=1 //here I reset all variables to one, because I will work on another file
    number=1
    MGD_mol_index=MGD$number
done
```

But I have a problem, this code will be extremely long, because I need to write this 129 times
s/$(($MGD_atom_index+x))/$MGD_mol_index/g; ,where x is a number from 1 to 128)
and I also think that my program could be slow. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { grp = 129 }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i == ($i+0) ) {
            $i = "MGD" (int($i/grp)+1)
        }
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
MGD674 SOL4504
MGD675 SOL5240
MGD675 SOL4251
SOL15 MGD297
SOL17 MGD277
SOL110 MGD319
```

so what you want in your shell script is this with GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
#!/bin/env bash
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN { grp = 129 }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i == ($i+0) ) {
            $i = "MGD" (int($i/grp)+1)
        }
    }
    print
}
' 'new2_'{1..100}'.ndx'
```

or this with any awk:

```
#!/bin/env bash
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
for index in {1..100}; do
    awk '
    BEGIN { grp = 129 }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ( $i == ($i+0) ) {
                $i = "MGD" (int($i/grp)+1)
            }
        }
        print
    }
    ' "new2_$index.ndx" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "new2_$index.ndx"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
So here `tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1` program creates a temporary file and exit 1 means:  Exit the shell if the directory or fifo could not be created? I dont know why you use that `if ( $i == ($i+0) )` it will be always true yes? because $i+0 = $i, so $i ==$i+0 will be always true

Comment: Correct but it's just a file, not a directory or  anything else. `$i == ($i+0)` is the idiomatic way to test for an input value being a number. If `$i` is any number (7, 3.14, 2e7, etc.) then that condition will be true but otherwise (e.g. `SOL15`) it'll be false. Try `echo '7 7s s7 3.14 2e7 SOL15' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i, $i+0, ($i==$i+0)}'` to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this awk is all you need.

```
awk '
    $1~/^[0-9]+$/{$1="MDG" int($1/129+1)}
    $2~/^[0-9]+$/{$2="MDG" int($2/129+1)}
    1
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
sed -E 's#\b([0-9]+)\b#MGD$((\1/129+1))#g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Convert all groups of numbers to the required format, by substituting a shell numeric expression, prepended by `MGD` and then evaluating the expression by using the echo command.